# debugging two sites in same solution

Tags: asp.net-mvc, iis-express

I have a strange error here.

I have a solution with 2 mvc sites. One for an API and one for an Admin interface.

They run under two different ports; api = :3344, admin = 1234.

Whenever I run one of them, separately, each of them work fine. When I wish to run them both side-by-side (mostly for debugging) I get an error.

"Could not load file or assembly 'Newtonsoft.Json' or one of its dependencies."

Any hints ?

Comment: How do you run them "side by side"?

Comment: Is Newtonsoft.Json referenced with the same version from both sites?

Comment: @MarkSeemann funny you mention it. I tried to update the package and then I was given a new error, for a Microsoft.Data.Edm. Which I have not referenced anywhere, put is used by a Azure component.

Then I deleted the reference to that, and now it works. For now!

Nuget is sometimes very frustrating!